# .d.ts typescript file for a javascript library

Tags: javascript, typescript, migration, ionic3

I'm trying to create a description file to use a javascript library with typescript.

At the moment I'm trying to follow those guides: [TypeScript Official website](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) and [Medium guide to migrate to typescript](https://medium.com/@chris_72272/migrating-to-typescript-write-a-declaration-file-for-a-third-party-npm-module-b1f75808ed2)

To be specific I'm trying to create a typescript description file for [leaflet-icon-pulse](https://github.com/mapshakers/leaflet-icon-pulse), which I thought was simple enough to start with

So I downloaded the git project, created **tsconfig.json** as follows

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "./built",
  "allowJs": true,
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "strictNullChecks": true,
  "target": "es5",
  "module": "commonjs"
},
"include": [
  "./src/**/*"
],
"exclude": [
  "node_modules"
]
}
```

Then I tried to convert the file **L.Icon.Pulse.js** to **L.Icon.Pulse.ts**, but I started getting error like:

```
Property X does not exists on type Y
```

So as far as I understood I need to let the js be and simply create a L.Icon.Pulse.d.ts file

Right now mine looks like:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
declare module 'leaflet' {
     function Pulse(options?: any): any;
}
```

But now I have no idea how to precede, and I was not able to find a good tutorial or example on how to go on.

Someone can give me some tips on how to procede?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the d.ts file, I would maybe go on by ignoring the typescript errors.

So, you install leaflet-pulse-icon through npm:

```
npm install leaflet-pulse-icon
```

...and you include it in your component:

```
import 'leaflet-pulse-icon';
```

To avoid the error, just make TypeScript ignore the typings for a while.. So, instead of:

```
let pulsingIcon = L.icon.pulse({iconSize:[20,20],color:'red'});
```

You should use:

```
let pulsingIcon = (L as any).icon.pulse({iconSize:[20,20],color:'red'});
```

...using L as "of any type" variable.

Of course, TypeScript should not work without types(!) but occasionally, I find it convenient to bypass some errors using the ":any" way.